# How to download libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, libraries

Whenever I have to add certain library from the internet to my Android project, I add them inside the dependencies in the app level gradle script and it downloads the library for me. Is it possible to download these library files so that I can use them in other projects as well without downloading the whole library and dependency files again?

Comment: Put library's jar file inside libs folder.

Comment: @Malwinder that wasn't the question. It's how to download, not how to use

Comment: Dependencies are only downloaded once and cached on your computer for later user.  Look at all the contents of your .gradle/caches folder in your home directory. Gradle uses standard dependency resolution and caching tools to manage all this, and it's better to continue to allow it to manage your dependencies. This will save you a bunch of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to Maven central and download the libraries.

For example, [here is Volley](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library/1.0.19). Just click the download JAR button.

I would strongly recommend sticking with Gradle / Maven, though, to keep consistency with versions and appropriately handle additional dependencies for the libraries you want to download. They are called package managers for a reason, and they do their job well.

The libraries are actually downloaded to disk only once and shared between projects, they aren't downloaded for every new project.

Comment: But when I added the dependency  'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
, in one project, and tried to access in a new one, it again started to download a fresh copy.

Comment: It shouldn't if you have your Gradle cache setup properly

Comment: Yeah, now I fixed it. So it doesn't download the library again. But the issue is how can I find the downloaded libraries in Project structure-->app--> dependencies? Some libraries like butter knife is already present so it shows up. But for something like firebaseui it searched the internet and downloaded. But for the second time it doesn't show up in the dependencies. So I have to connect to the internet for it to show up again. However it doesn't download the library again. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: "It doesn't download the library again"... That's a good thing, right? I don't quite understand...  If you add the dependencies into Gradle, then I don't think they should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Put library's jar file inside libs folder.
Add this line in module level build.gradle (if not present):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     // Other libraries
}
```

Comment: As I said in the comments, the question was "Is it possible to download these library files" not "how to use them in a new project"

Answer (score 0):

Find the gradle dependency for your library and put it in dependencies of your build.gradle file. For Example,

```
    dependencies {
        // other dependencies
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    }
```

and then build the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just run into an issue where a coworker's AS instance wasn't syncing with the server. In that case, we simply had to manually invoke the "Sync Project with Gradle File". For whatever reason, his AS instance wasn't doing that automatically.