# Add Volley to android studio project manually, gradle offline

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

I am just a student with a very very slow internet connection and laptop. My problem is most methods of adding volley to my android studio projects requires me to use gradle online mode so it can download it.

My problem is my internet connection is very slow, and my laptop is also not that fast therefore gradle offline mode is the only thing keeping my laptop from dying everytime I use android studio.

Is there any manual way of adding volley to my project or any alternative you may know of?

Please help me, I am just a student so I do not know much.

Comment: Gradle downloads libraries just once read this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35972965/1562723

Answer (score 1):

You can use this volley library

compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.1.0'

Comment: That is now deprecated, we already have official dependency for Volley.

Comment: use this version :-  compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1'

Comment: This is the official one `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`

Comment: ok then use this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Download Volley Jar File from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HGUM4c0YwpZFp2aUlnNjJvV2c/view

Steps to add Jar file in Android Studio :

- Put the Volley jar (in my case, volley.jar) into the libs folder
- Right click it and hit 'Add as library'

After Adding Check your build.gradle at app module, you get it added `implementation files('libs/volley.jar')`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```